# Unable to insert text into HTML from input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, text, insert, field

I am new to programming and I have been trying to write a script using jQuery that will take the value from an input field, and insert it into a paragraph once the button has been clicked.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lowercase">lowercase</label>
        <input id="lowercase" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="type in lowercase">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn">Convert Text to Uppercase</button>  
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="uppercasetext">
    <h3>UPPERCASE</h3>
    <p id="convertedtext"></p>
  </div>
```

And here is the jQuery that I wrote:

```
$((function() {
 $("#button").onClick(function(){
     ("#convertedtext").val($("#lowercase").val());
 });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: use jQuery().text() rather than jQuery().val() function. jQuery().val() only works with input & select field

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
$(function() {  //remove one extra bracket from here
  $("#button").click(function(){ // instead of 'onClick' use 'click'
     $("#convertedtext").text($("#lowercase").val()); // instead of '.val()' use '.text()' or '.html()'
  });
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {  //remove one extra bracket from here
  $("#button").on("click",function(){ // instead of 'onClick' use 'click'
     $("#convertedtext").text($("#lowercase").val()); // instead of '.val()' use '.text()' or '.html()'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use click event

```
$((function() {
 $("#button").on("click",function(){
    $("#convertedtext").text($("#lowercase").val());
 });
});
```

There is no onClick in jQuery its in javascript . And even in that case also you have to use it inside input tag only not outside it. like `<input type="text" onClick="your_function()".....`

Comment: instead of `("#convertedtext").val($("#lowercase").val());` it should be `$("#convertedtext").text($("#lowercase").val());` you missed `$` and instead of `.val()` it should be `.html()` or `.text()` as shown in my answer.

Comment: @Kartikeya , yes I overlooked it , i thought its onClick issue only :) Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append using this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#button").click(function(){
         $("#convertedtext").append($("#lowercase").val());
     });
});
```

Else if you want to insert using this:

```
$(function() {
     $("#button").click(function(){
         $("#convertedtext").html($("#lowercase").val());
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do below steps

1. Include the jquery file
2. Change button type to button, so your form will not submit on click.
3. include below code in head

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").on('click', function(){
        $("#convertedtext").html($("#lowercase").val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for all your answers and for answering so quickly.
I tried the answers suggested but for some reason I still could not get it to work. I ended with a solution that did work. I am sure a PRO has a much better way of doing it. I would really love to know your thoughts on this method.

CSS:

```
p.uppercase{
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blanks form").submit(function(event){
      var lowercase = $("input#lowercase").val();
      $(".uppercase").text(lowercase);
      event.preventDefault();
    });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/uppercase.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/uppercase.js"></script>

    <title>Uppercase</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
  <h2>Type something in all lowercase and see it in uppercase.</h2>
  <div id="blanks">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lowercase">lowercase</label>
        <input id="lowercase" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="type in lowercase">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn">Convert Text to Uppercase</button>  
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="uppercasetext">
    <h3>UPPERCASE</h3>
    <p>Here is your text in uppercase: <span class="uppercase"></span></p>

     </div> 
   </div>       

 </body>
</html>
```